# How to deal with Deep Reinforcement Learning with large action set in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, large-data, reinforcement-learning

I want to implement DRL with large action set using popular way to deal with large action set such as policy gradient or actor-critic.

However, I have some trouble to exploit the algorithms in TensorFlow because of a memory issue. For example, I have 3125000 actions and VRAM (to use TenforFlow GPU version) is usually about 10 GiB.

I want to know general ways to deal with DRL with large action set in TensorFlow.

Comment: Are those all actions distinct?

Comment: Yes it all distinct!